# Disabled messages still showing

Tags: nodes

I'm trying to use the [Disable Messages Module](https://www.drupal.org/project/disable_messages) to hide some messages. For example the message `Proposal has been updated.` (because I'm using a wizard and updates every step).

[image]

These are my configuration settings of the disable messages module:

[image]

[image]

I've cleared my cache but the message is still showing. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Please keep in mind that images here gets shrunk to 630px. If you want your screenshots to be readable, resize your browser to something under that width before taking a screen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be:

```
Proposal .* has been updated
```

and not

```
Proposal *. has been updated
```

What you want is

```
Proposal, space, any number of any characters, space, ...
```

But what you wrote is:

```
Proposal, any number of spaces, one of any character, space, ...
```